# how to associate a function to a treeview child in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

hey i am new to javafx and gui building

so i have a treeview with me and multiple roots and each root has multiple child nodes

```
@FXML
TreeView<String> bro;

TreeItem<String> root=new TreeItem<>("root");
TreeItem<String> child = new TreeItem<>("child");
TreeItem<String> child2 = new TreeItem<>("child");
TreeItem<String> child3 = new TreeItem<>("child");
TreeItem<String> child4 = new TreeItem<>("child");
TreeItem<String> child5 = new TreeItem<>("child");

public void initialize(){

root.getChildren().add(child);
         root.getChildren().add(child2);
         root.getChildren().add(child3);
         root.getChildren().add(child4);
         root.getChildren().add(child5);
         root.setExpanded(true);
bro.setRoot(root);

}
```

so since the treeview as been initialisei would like to associate or bind child2 with a fucntion that i have that runs whenever i click on child2

```
public void openWindow(){
   // code to open new window 
}
```

everytime child2 is clicked i would like `openwindow()` function which opens a new window to run

i would also like to know when child2 is selected if that is possible

how do i do this

thanks

Comment: Every time it's clicked? Or every time it becomes selected?

Comment: clicked is what i want

Answer (score 1):

To respond to mouse clicks on cells, set a cell factory on the `TreeView`, so that you can add an event handler to the cells:

```
bro.setCellFactory(tv -> {
    TreeCell<String> cell = new TreeCell<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(item);
        }
    };

    cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        if (cell.getTreeItem() == child2) {
            openWindow();
        }
    });

    return cell ;
});
```

To know when an item is selected, register a listener with the tree's selection model's selected item property:

```
bro.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    if (newSelection == child2) {
        System.out.println("child2 selected");
    }
});
```